# implement a unix pipe with python cmd module?

Tags: python, windows, shell, cmd, pipe

I'm implement a simple shell using python's `cmd` module.
Now, I'd like to implement a unix pipe in this shell, that is when I type:

```
ls | grep "a"
```

it will pass the result of `do_ls` to the input of `do_grep`,
what's the simplest way to do this?
Sorry CryptoJones, I forgot to say that my platform is Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple example which could help you:

```
from cmd import Cmd

class PipelineExample(Cmd):

    def do_greet(self, person):
        if person:
            greeting = "hello, " + person
        else:
            greeting = 'hello'
        self.output = greeting

    def do_echo(self, text):
        self.output = text

    def do_pipe(self, args):
        buffer = None
        for arg in args:
            s = arg
            if buffer:
                # This command just adds the output of a previous command as the last argument
                s += ' ' + buffer
            self.onecmd(s)
            buffer = self.output

    def postcmd(self, stop, line):
        if hasattr(self, 'output') and self.output:
            print self.output
            self.output = None
        return stop

    def parseline(self, line):
        if '|' in line:
            return 'pipe', line.split('|'), line
        return Cmd.parseline(self, line)

    def do_EOF(self, line):
        return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    PipelineExample().cmdloop()
```

Here is an example session:

```
(Cmd) greet wong
hello, wong
(Cmd) echo wong | greet
hello, wong
(Cmd) echo wong | greet | greet
hello, hello, wong
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is probably to store the output of your `do_ls` in a buffer and feed it to `do_grep`. You probably want to do it line by line or by groups of lines, rather than in a single go, especially if you want to implement a `more` command.

A more complete approach would be to run all of your commands in sub-processes and rely on an existing standard library module for pipe support, e.g. [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html).

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use the [cmd2](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/cmd2) module. It is a replacement for `cmd` with additional features.

See the [Output redirection](http://packages.python.org/cmd2/freefeatures.html?highlight=pipe#output-redirection) section of its documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Use the built in pipe function, not cmd.

http://docs.python.org/library/pipes.html